# how implement a complicated div in div (when hover event)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

I want to implement a div like this[image]

I want to show left image when Hover it showed right image . I'm new in CSS and have any idea to implement this :/ . can anyone help me ? Thanks
(this image courtesy of Nike.com )

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of ways to do it. For example: Make a div that looks like the second one as a regular div and put it right where we see now, and make it hidden at css like this

```
div#implantedDiv: { display:none }
```

And at your javascript put code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainDiv").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#implantedDiv").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS:

```css
.product {
  float:left;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  min-height:150px;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  font-family:helvetica;
}

.product .details {
  display:none;  /* initial state */
}
.product:hover .details {
  display:block; /* show only on parent's hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="general-info">GENERAL INFO</div>
  <div class="details">DETAILS</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="general-info">GENERAL INFO</div>
  <div class="details">DETAILS</div>
</div>
```